# How do I disable a USB mouse by its VID and PID but still be able to read data from it?

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

I have two USB mice connected to my PC. I need to disable just one of them (by VID and PID) in such a way that the Windows mouse pointer won't be affected by its movement but programs will still be able to access the port and read the mouse data.

Any ideas? It's important that **the OS keeps access to the mouse**, so that the program can manipulate the data it provides.

Comment: What interface does your program use for accessing the mouse data?

Comment: Actually, i didn't write the program yet. I'm planning on using C#, but first I need access to the USB port, which is prevented by windows.

Comment: Can you see if devcon.exe helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to disable it through the Device Manager:

[Disable mouse with Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1V5i.png)